# How to save an output variable using ode45 [MATLAB]?

Tags: matlab, simulation, ode, differential-equations

I have a second order differential equation

```
function Xdot =second_order(t,X)
y=X(1);
y_d=X(2);

Xdot=zeros(2,1);
Xdot(1)=y_d;
Xdot(2)= -5*y_d-7;   
y_dd=Xdot(2);
end
```

Using MATLAB ode45 command, I am able to simulate it `[t,X]=ode45(@(t,X)second_order(t,X),tspan,X0);`
I am able to capture the two state variables y and y_d in vectors as a function of time in this manner.

I want to capture y_dd in vector as a function of time but I am unable to save it. How can I treat it as an output variable?
I have tried the following change to my function file `function [Xdot,y_dd] =second_order(t,X)` but i don't understand how to use the ode45 command so I can save y_dd as well during its execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just evaluate the `second_order` function on the trajectory points. The second component of the result is the desired derivative.

You also have evaluation function `deval` that can access the "dense output" interpolation of the solution and the slopes at those points, see https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/deval.html#bu7i1mf

```
sol=ode45(@second_order,[tspan(1) tspan(end)] ,X0); 
[X,Xp] = deval(sol,tspan)
```

You should find that the first derivatives in `X(:,2)` and `Xp(:,1)` are (almost) identical, the second derivative is then in `Xp(:,2)`.